# Symmetry in partial derivatives.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, derivatives

I was wondering how the relationship $$x_j \partial_i f(x) = x_i \partial_j f(x)$$ means, that a function has rotational symmetry? I mean with rotational symmetric, that the value of $f$ at a point $x$ depends only on $\|x\|_2$.

Or more precisely: Is there any $C_1(\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}; \mathbb{R})$ function, that has no rotational symmetry, but fulfills this equation for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is: Does the relation imply $\nabla f(x) \cdot y = 0$ whenever $y$ is orthogonal to $x$?

Assume without loss of generality that $x = (1, 0, \ldots, 0)$. Take $j \neq 1$ and $i = 1$. Then the relation says $0 = \delta_{1 i} \partial_j f(x) = \partial_j f(x)$. Hence $\partial_j f(x) = 0$ for all $j \neq 1$. Or: $\nabla f(x) \cdot y = 0$ for all $y$ orthogonal to $x$.

Now take a path $x(t)$ lying in any sphere (of positive radius) centered at the origin. Then $(f(x(t)))' = \nabla f(x(t)) \cdot \dot{x}(t) = 0$, because $x(t) \cdot \dot{x}(t) = 0$. Why? Differentiate $\|x(t)\|_2^2 = x(t)^T x(t)$.

Hence the answer is yes, the relation does imply rotational symmetry.

On second thinking, it is not clear that no generality is lost by assuming $x = (1, 0, \ldots, 0)$. Take any rotation matrix $U$, and $g(x) := f(U x)$. Then $\nabla g(x) \cdot y  = \nabla f(U x) \cdot U y$. Or, reversing the substitution, $\nabla g(U^T x) \cdot U^T y  = \nabla f(x) \cdot y$. Hence yes: rotating $x$ and the deviation $y$ by the same matrix does not change the value of the quantity that we are after.

Comment: I don't understand your comment/answer. Do you want to help me or is this an actual question?

Comment: was meant as a hint.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see what both questions have in common. Could you at least sketch, how my question is equivalent to your hint? Btw, I welcome your help, but so far, I do not see the relationship.

Comment: Rotational symmetry means, the value of $f(x)$ doesn't change when you move $x$ to $x + y$ ($y$ is "infinitesimal") on the sphere, but it may if you move it out of sphere. Out of sphere (perpendicularly) means $y$ is parallel to $x$, and $\nabla f(x) \cdot y$ is the change. On the sphere means $y$ is orthogonal to $x$, in which case the change should be zero.

Comment: so what you are giving there is another definition of rotational symmetry, but not a reformulation of my question?

Comment: @Lost1: I believe it contributes substantially towards it.

Comment: Erm sorry, i was probably day dreaming when i reviewed this, apoplogies...